# ListView showing System.Data.DataRowView instead of DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, datatable

My problem is that every row of the ListView shows "System.Data.DataRowView" after I change the ListView Template with a Style.

I've defined the DataTable here:

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();
lsvOutput.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;
```

This is the XAML for the columns:

```
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="column1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding column1}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="column2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding column2}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="column3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding column3}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

This is the part where it breaks I'm assuming:

```
                    <ContentPresenter
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I replaced this:

```
<ContentPresenter
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
```

With this:

```
<GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx